# No Admin User on fresh Wubi Install

Tags: wubi, sudo, administrator

I just installed Wubi fresh (Win 7; Ubuntu 12.10).

After booting into Ubuntu for the first time, my first instinct is to:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

However, I'm quickly prompted with:

```
[user] is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

**I checked user settings and it appears that there are NO admin accounts:**

[image: User Accounts]

How can I resolve this? And why did Wubi set me up with a non-admin account?

Comment: Did you have to login as guest or did your userid get created? Does `cat /etc/os-release` say 12.10?

Comment: I logged in as my user, "nathanbrauer". `cat /etc/os-release` does indicate that I'm on 12.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend [filing a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+filebug) and attaching your logfile (from the `%TEMP%` directory in Windows: `wubi-12.10-rev273.log`.

You could try to fix it manually by booting into the Recovery menu: hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key after selecting Ubuntu, select *Advanced options* and then *Recoverymode*. Once you see the recovery menu select the root prompt.

First you need to remount the drive read/write:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

And then add yourself to the sudo group and reboot:

```
usermod -a -G sudo nathanbrauer
reboot
```

I've never heard of this problem before on a Wubi install, so don't know if this will fix it or whether there is some other underlying problem. But it's probably quicker to try than reinstalling. I do recommend filing that bug report though.

Answer (score -1):

you can type

## sudo su -

Enter your user password now you are in a root user then you can change your root password by typing

## passwd

it will ask for password and re-enter it again

Comment: "`[user] is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`"